# How do I get a .desktop in KDE to open a new browser window?

Tags: kde, opensuse, desktop, freedesktop

I setup a link to web app that my company uses on my desktop, which resulted in a `.desktop` file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=/home/kris/Pictures/gplus.png
Name[en_US]=Google Plus
Name=Google Plus
Type=Link
URL[$e]=https://plus.google.com/
```

This works pretty well, but I can't figure out how to add an option to force it to open in a new window, or possibly even as an "app" window. I have tested in a console that what I want will work:

```
$ firefox -new-window plus.google.com
```

Does anyone know of a way to modify the `.desktop` to do this? Is the only way to re-do it as a `Exec` style launcher? Is there an editor in KDE for this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to setup a "link to application" in the context menu like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Exec=firefox -new-window http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151004/how-do-i-get-a-desktop-in-kde-to-open-a-new-browser-window
GenericName=
Icon=exec
MimeType=
Name=Stackexchange
Path=<whereever you want>
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```